# Step Function Call Lambda Passing Body, Headers

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a simple step function - to invoke a lambda.  I want the step function to pass header, query parameters, and body to the API.  I think I found how to define the headers and query parameters.  Below is my state machine definition.  How do I pass what I want as the body?  Do I have headers and query parameters defined properly?  I am calling a lambda function over which I have no control so I cannot change anything there.

```
{
  "StartAt": "InvokeLambdaState",
  "States": {
    "InvokeLambdaState": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": ">>>AWS ARN<<<",
      "Parameters": {
        "Method": "POST",
        "Headers": {
          "header1": "value1"
        },
        "QueryParameters": {
          "Param1": "value1"
        },
        ">>>BODY TO BE PASSED<<<"
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A lambda does not accept header or query parameters. Are you talking about invoking an API gateway instead? Or are you talking about calling a function URL?

Comment: I have a lambda API function - I want my step function to invoke the lambda API function.  I understand it goes through the API gateway.  But if I call the function using Insomnia I define: query params, url, header params, json body - I am trying to do the same with step function

Comment: There is no lambda api function, that terminology does not exist. You have lambda functions and / or API Gateways. What is behind the API gateway does not matter for the purpose of the stepfunction. And if you know what actual resource / action you want to invoke check the documentation for that and see what its parameters are. And to find the right documentation it is essential to use the right terminology.

Answer (score 0):

from the responses my question did not make sense - I get it.  I will review document for API Gateway in an attempt to do the action I am trying - to, ultimately, pass headers, query parameters, and json body to my lambda API.